# How to automatically deploy a jar from s3 to aws lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I want to automatically deploy a jar to `aws-lamda` whenever there is any change in the version of the jar in `s3 bucket`.

For example:
There is one `S3 bucket` say `lambdadeploytest`and a `Lamda function`name `autoDeployTest`. I have stored an object `test.jar` in `lambdadeploytest`.

Whenever there is I **upload a new version** of the object `test.jar`, `test.jar` will be automatically **deployed** to `autoDeployTest` lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a lambda function ...
At high level the steps are

- create a lambda function that will download the `test.jar` and use the jar to create / update the `autoDeployTest` lambda function.
- configure your new lambda function to be triggered when `test.jar` is modified on S3
- configure the new lambda function with permissions to read your S3 bucket and to deploy code on Lambda.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) to create a lambda function that would be triggered by S3 events.  [This is the Lambda API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionCode.html) your lambda function can call to update `autodeployTest` code.

Pseudo Code would be like this :

```
read JSON event object to get the bucket name and object name (bucket_name, test.jar)

download a copy of the object (test.jar) to the lambda container 

(do additional check on the jar file if required) 

call Lambda's UpdateFunctionCode to update autoDeployTest function code with the jar.
```

Comment: Can you please me by showing an example to write the java code for point no. 1. I am completely new to aws so facing difficulty in understanding UpdateFunctionCodeResult.

Comment: the Java doc is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#updateFunctionCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.UpdateFunctionCodeRequest-

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way to do this is to trigger the deployment after uploading new JAR file to S3. Lambda itself won't handle that for you, unless you plan to use another Lambda for that purpose (which I personally wouldn't).

It's not clear to me what you use for uploads of JAR file - if it's e.g. Terraform, that would be the way to go. If you uploaded new version of JAR file using AWS CLI, you can stick to the same tool to trigger Lambda deployment.

Comment: I am planning to use serverless.yml